# Is it possible to have a mouseover trigger over typed text in inputs?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, html-input

Suppose I have a simple `<input type="text">`, is it possible to add a Javascript listener to listen for when a user mouseover a typed text inside that input? If so, could I also know exactly which letter (or position in the string) they are currently moused over?

I am willing to use JS frameworks like jQuery to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743266/retrieving-character-position-in-case-of-a-mouse-over-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Letters in an input are not HTML elements. You need HTML elements to have event handlers.

The only way to accomplish this is to hide the input box and have a fake one over top and wrap each individual letter in a SPAN as you type. That way each letter is within an actual HTML element.